# Why use Handler?

Tags: android

I came across this code in a very basic Handler tutorial. The code is working fine but I do not understand why I have to use Handler for   `progressDialog.dismiss()` ???   I removed the Handler part and placed   `progressDialog.dismiss()` in the `run()` method and it worked fine.   So why used Handler???

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class HandlerThread extends Activity{

    private Button start;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fetchData();
            }

        });
    }



    protected void fetchData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Doing...");
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(8000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                      messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    }
        }.start();


    }



    private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with your observation. Calling progressDialog.dismiss() inside run() method, which is running on a non-UI thread, will throw an exception.

Comment: @Sameer not necessarily. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12313049/165674).

Comment: simply you cannot change state of any view from working (or background) thread. Only from `UI` thread you can change it so for this approach is usually used `Handler` or `AsyncTask`

Comment: @deceiver It's better to point out that the `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask` runs on a non-UI thread. So methods of a `View` can not be called from it. The other callbacks of `AsyncTask` run on the UI thread, though.

Comment: OnProgressUpdate and OnPostExecute :-))

Comment: On a completely unrelated note: Android comes shipped with a [`HandlerThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) class, so naming your activity class identical to something that already exists may not be the best move. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[From the documentation of `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> *You must always be on the UI thread when calling any method on any
>   view.* If you are doing work on other threads and want to update the
>   state of a view from that thread, you should use a `Handler`.

In your example, when you've to call the `dismiss()` method on the `ProgressDialog`, as per the above documentation, you must do so from the UI thread. The `messageHandler` is initialized to an instance of a `Handler` when the `HandlerThread` class is instantiated (presumably on the UI thread).

[From the documentation of `Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> Each `Handler` instance is associated with a single thread and that
>   thread's message queue. When you create a new `Handler`, it is bound to
>   the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from
>   that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message
>   queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

So to communicate with the UI thread from your new thread, just post a message to the `Handler` created on the UI thread.

If you call methods on a `View` from outside the UI thread, it invokes *undefined behaviour*, which means, it *may appear* to work fine. But it's not *always* guaranteed to work fine.

Answer (score 32):

### Why to use Handler in Android?

---

**First: Let us know what is thread:**

- Threads help in multi-tasking
- Threads can be taught as a mini process running under a main process
- Threads enable at-least the appearance parallel execution

**Second: Let us know about the application thread:-**

- When the android application is first started the runtime system will create a single main thread, this main thread will take care of execution of all the components in android

---

**Android UI-Toolkit is not thread safe**

- *As stated there are many components in the android main thread, now suppose one of the components takes a long time for execution then
  this makes the main thread **unresponsive** and it will **show the
  application unresponsive***
- Sub-threads cannot directly manipulate the application (main) thread
  in the android
- Handler acts as a interface and collects the messages from the
  sub-threads and update the main application thread one by one as the
  messages arrive, Thread handlers are implemented in main thread.

---

**Handler class:**

- For the purpose of multithreading we shall use handler class which
  comes from the package `android.os.Handler`
- Each thread is handled by one instance of handler class

[image: Figure]

- From the above figure we can see that Each thread is handled by one
  instance of the Handler class
- threads communicate between each other with the help of messages
- This handler class helps to maintain kind of sync-coordination b/w
  threads by allowing them to run together achieving multithreading

---

**Instance of handler is made**

```
Handler handlerObject = new Handler();
```

---

**Final piece on using handler is to use Runnable Interface:**

- handler class utilizes runnable interface to implement multithreading
- We override run method to execute a thread a specified number of time

---

```
Class NameOfClass implements Runnable
{
    Public void run()
    {
        //Body of run method
    }
}
```

---

**Putting all together**

```
//Create handler in the thread it should be associated with 
//in this case the UI thread
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            //Do time consuming stuff

            //The handler schedules the new runnable on the UI thread
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                //Ex.. using progressbar to set the pogress
                            //Updating the UI is done inside the Handler
            });
        }
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: Why there are two "Run() methods in new Runnable() body? Could it be done only with one method?

Comment: What about that simple solution: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   public void run() {

   }

  });

Comment: I have not tried it ... but your answer looks much simpler, Yes indeed !

Comment: @Unicorn i want more explanation on Asynchronous task and difference between these two...

Comment: @ [Satheesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2207359/satheesh) ..... [Have a click at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17765121/1083093) ..... This might give you the info you are searching !

Comment: to my limited understanding asyncTask is used to delegate work to the background whereas handlers are used to pass information between threads. Did I get the concept right ?

Answer (score 6):

The easier the better.
Instead of using a handler, you could try to use the following code:

```
runOnUiThread(
    new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        { 

        //Update user interface here

        } 
    }
);
```

Don't make your life to complicated ;)

Comment: You need a reference to an activity to post in the UI thread, while with a handler you only need itself. Another solution is to use View.post(Runnable action) if you just want to hold Views references.

Answer (score 2):

when an application starts, android system launch a process having a main thread, which is responsible to process UI Rendering, and Events. The Android UI isnot thread safe, so we can access android UI only by Event thread. In your program you have defined another thread than event by following code block:

```
 new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(8000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                  messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }
    }.start();
```

now if you want to dismiss progress dialog, you can do it only in event thread.
Handler is used process/handle messages of a message queue. Handler associates with a thread, in your case its in event thread, as by default it would associate thread, in which it is being created. by messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage() another thread send a message to handler, and handler, process this message, in handleMessage method.

Comment: What does it mean, if something is or is not thread safe? Could you please explain in your answer?